# How to make an Android version for a web site

Tags: android, web

I have a website and i need to make an Android version for it.
How to do with web langages (Not Java :s) ? i think it's possible with HTML5.
So what do i need to do ?
Thank you

Comment: You just make a webpage that looks good on all sizes off mobile screens. You don't even need html5.
Edit: Usually you will redirect from your regular webpage to the mobile webpage if a mobile device connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy to develop a web apps for mobiles if you use something like

http://jquerymobile.com/ (uses Html5, JavaScript and CSS)

Or

http://jqtouch.com/ (uses HTML, JavaScript and CSS)

There are loads of others if you search, just the above two are the ones I am most familiar with and have found very easy to use.